# How can I handle errors I get from the liquibase updateDatabase ant task

Tags: database, ant, error-handling, return, liquibase

I'm currently working on some ant for applying liquibase changes to databases.
I'd like to be able to handle errors that I get in ant from the liquibase updateDatabase task. Here is what I have right now in my build file (bear in mind what I have now works fine I just need to be able to handle errors I might get from running the liquibase).

```
<target name="update_db" depends="prepare">
  <taskdef resource="liquibasetasks.properties">
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
  </taskdef>    

  <updateDatabase
        changeLogFile="${db.changelog.file}"
        driver="${database.driver}"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/${db.name}"
        username="${user}"
        password="${password}"
        promptOnNonLocalDatabase="not local database"
        dropFirst="false"
        classpathref="classpath"
  />    
</target>
```

Currently when I get an error I get something similar to this (from a situation I created to demonstrate):

```
BUILD FAILED
MYPATH\build.xml:15: The following error occurred while executing this line:
MYPATH\\build.xml:117: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed   
 for change set PATH/2.20.9/tables.xml::FFP-1384::AUSER:
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE        
test.widget ADD full_screen BIT(1) DEFAULT 0: Duplicate column name   'full_screen'
.............. and a the wall of text continues
```

Ideally I would like to be able to get the return code (rather than this block of text) from liquibase into ant and then based on that do something such as :

```
<echo message="this failed because ${reason}"/>
```

but not limited to that.

Is there some way for me to obtain the return code from liquibase? My best guess is that similar to the ant exec task, by default the return code is ignored and I'm hoping there is some way for me to get at it. Any suggestions welcome.

edit: Vaguely similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856564/liquibase-3-0-2-logging-to-error-console

Comment: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/ant/updatedatabase_ant_task.html Seems there is no way to get a return code -- the task doesn't implement it. The reason `exec` can get a return code is that it executes an external program -- that means a new process. For common Ant tasks, it is just a piece of code, executed in the same process of the current Ant build, so there is no way to get any "return code". For ur instance, if the task connects to the db via socket, or directly opens the database, there will be no new process, thus no return code.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the case, I have now utilised the ant contrib try catch task which atleast lets me handle the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ant contrib trycatch task has enabled me to handle the error, which turned out to be a suitable fix since the stack trace is actually useful to see anyway.

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html

```
<trycatch property="foo" reference="bar">
  <try>
    <fail>Tada!</fail>
  </try>

  <catch>
    <echo>In &lt;catch&gt;.</echo>
  </catch>

  <finally>
    <echo>In &lt;finally&gt;.</echo>
  </finally>
</trycatch>
```

You need to download the ant contrib jar and if you don't want to place it in your ANT_HOME then you can use

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="PATH TO JAR"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```